# Codec Errors in Python

Tags: python, character-encoding, byte

Does anyone know the name of a codec that can translate any random assortment of bytes into a string? I have been getting the following error after encoding, encrypting, and decoding a string in **tkinter.Text.**

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode
byte 0x99 in position 151: unexpected code byte
```

Code used to generate the error follow below. The UTF8 codec listed at the top has problems translating some bytes back into a string. What I am looking for is an answer that solves the problem, not direction.

```
from tkinter import *
import traceback
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

CODEC = 'utf8'

################################################################################

class MarkovDemo:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.prompt_size = Label(master, anchor=W, text='Encode Word Size')
        self.prompt_size.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        self.size_entry = Entry(master)
        self.size_entry.insert(0, '8')
        self.size_entry.pack(fill=X)

        self.prompt_plain = Label(master, anchor=W, text='Plaintext Characters')
        self.prompt_plain.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        self.plain_entry = Entry(master)
        self.plain_entry.insert(0, '""')
        self.plain_entry.pack(fill=X)

        self.showframe = Frame(master)
        self.showframe.pack(fill=X, anchor=W)

        self.showvar = StringVar(master)
        self.showvar.set("encode")

        self.showfirstradio = Radiobutton(self.showframe,
                                          text="Encode Plaintext",
                                          variable=self.showvar,
                                          value="encode",
                                          command=self.reevaluate)
        self.showfirstradio.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.showallradio = Radiobutton(self.showframe,
                                        text="Decode Cyphertext",
                                        variable=self.showvar,
                                        value="decode",
                                        command=self.reevaluate)
        self.showallradio.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.inputbox = ScrolledText(master, width=60, height=10, wrap=WORD)
        self.inputbox.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.dynamic_var = IntVar()
        self.dynamic_box = Checkbutton(master, variable=self.dynamic_var,
                                       text='Dynamic Evaluation',
                                       offvalue=False, onvalue=True,
                                       command=self.reevaluate)
        self.dynamic_box.pack()

        self.output = Label(master, anchor=W, text="This is your output:")
        self.output.pack(fill=X)

        self.outbox = ScrolledText(master, width=60, height=10, wrap=WORD)
        self.outbox.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.inputbox.bind('<Key>', self.reevaluate)

        def select_all(event=None):
            event.widget.tag_add(SEL, 1.0, 'end-1c')
            event.widget.mark_set(INSERT, 1.0)
            event.widget.see(INSERT)
            return 'break'
        self.inputbox.bind('<Control-Key-a>', select_all)
        self.outbox.bind('<Control-Key-a>', select_all)
        self.inputbox.bind('<Control-Key-/>', lambda event: 'break')
        self.outbox.bind('<Control-Key-/>', lambda event: 'break')
        self.outbox.config(state=DISABLED)

    def reevaluate(self, event=None):
        if event is not None:
            if event.char == '':
                return
        if self.dynamic_var.get():
            text = self.inputbox.get(1.0, END)[:-1]
            if len(text) < 10:
                return
            text = text.replace('\n \n', '\n\n')
            mode = self.showvar.get()
            assert mode in ('decode', 'encode'), 'Bad mode!'
            if mode == 'encode':
                # Encode Plaintext
                try:
                    # Evaluate the plaintext characters
                    plain = self.plain_entry.get()
                    if plain:
                        PC = eval(self.plain_entry.get())
                    else:
                        PC = ''
                        self.plain_entry.delete(0, END)
                        self.plain_entry.insert(0, '""')
                    # Evaluate the word size
                    size = self.size_entry.get()
                    if size:
                        XD = int(size)
                        while grid_size(text, XD, PC) > 1 << 20:
                            XD -= 1
                    else:
                        XD = 0
                        grid = 0
                        while grid <= 1 << 20:
                            grid = grid_size(text, XD, PC)
                            XD += 1
                        XD -= 1
                    # Correct the size and encode
                    self.size_entry.delete(0, END)
                    self.size_entry.insert(0, str(XD))
                    cyphertext, key, prime = encrypt_str(text, XD, PC)
                except:
                    traceback.print_exc()
                else:
                    buffer = ''
                    for block in key:
                        buffer += repr(block)[2:-1] + '\n'
                    buffer += repr(prime)[2:-1] + '\n\n' + cyphertext
                    self.outbox.config(state=NORMAL)
                    self.outbox.delete(1.0, END)
                    self.outbox.insert(END, buffer)
                    self.outbox.config(state=DISABLED)
            else:
                # Decode Cyphertext
                try:
                    header, cypher = text.split('\n\n', 1)
                    lines = header.split('\n')
                    for index, item in enumerate(lines):
                        try:
                            lines[index] = eval('b"' + item + '"')
                        except:
                            lines[index] = eval("b'" + item + "'")
                    plain = decrypt_str(cypher, tuple(lines[:-1]), lines[-1])
                except:
                    traceback.print_exc()
                else:
                    self.outbox.config(state=NORMAL)
                    self.outbox.delete(1.0, END)
                    self.outbox.insert(END, plain)
                    self.outbox.config(state=DISABLED)
        else:
            text = self.inputbox.get(1.0, END)[:-1]
            text = text.replace('\n \n', '\n\n')
            mode = self.showvar.get()
            assert mode in ('decode', 'encode'), 'Bad mode!'
            if mode == 'encode':
                try:
                    XD = int(self.size_entry.get())
                    PC = eval(self.plain_entry.get())
                    size = grid_size(text, XD, PC)
                    assert size
                except:
                    pass
                else:
                    buffer = 'Grid size will be:\n' + convert(size)
                    self.outbox.config(state=NORMAL)
                    self.outbox.delete(1.0, END)
                    self.outbox.insert(END, buffer)
                    self.outbox.config(state=DISABLED)

################################################################################

import random
CRYPT = random.SystemRandom()

################################################################################

# This section includes functions that
# can test the required key and bootstrap.

# sudoko_key
#  - should be a proper "markov" key
def _check_sudoku_key(sudoku_key):
    # Ensure key is a tuple with more than one item.
    assert isinstance(sudoku_key, tuple), '"sudoku_key" must be a tuple'
    assert len(sudoku_key) > 1, '"sudoku_key" must have more than one item'
    # Test first item.
    item = sudoku_key[0]
    assert isinstance(item, bytes), 'first item must be an instance of bytes'
    assert len(item) > 1, 'first item must have more than one byte'
    assert len(item) == len(set(item)), 'first item must have unique bytes'
    # Test the rest of the key.
    for obj in sudoku_key[1:]:
        assert isinstance(obj, bytes), 'remaining items must be of bytes'
        assert len(obj) == len(item), 'all items must have the same length'
        assert len(obj) == len(set(obj)), \
               'remaining items must have unique bytes'
        assert len(set(item)) == len(set(item).union(set(obj))), \
               'all items must have the same bytes'

# boot_strap
#  - should be a proper "markov" bootstrap
#  - we will call this a "primer"
# sudoko_key
#  - should be a proper "markov" key
def _check_boot_strap(boot_strap, sudoku_key):
    assert isinstance(boot_strap, bytes), '"boot_strap" must be a bytes object'
    assert len(boot_strap) == len(sudoku_key) - 1, \
           '"boot_strap" length must be one less than "sudoku_key" length'
    item = sudoku_key[0]
    assert len(set(item)) == len(set(item).union(set(boot_strap))), \
           '"boot_strap" may only have bytes found in "sudoku_key"'

################################################################################

# This section includes functions capable
# of creating the required key and bootstrap.

# bytes_set should be any collection of bytes
#  - it should be possible to create a set from them
#  - these should be the bytes on which encryption will follow
# word_size
#  - this will be the size of the "markov" chains program uses
#  - this will be the number of dimensions the "grid" will have
#  - one less character will make up bootstrap (or primer)
def make_sudoku_key(bytes_set, word_size):
    key_set = set(bytes_set)
    blocks = []
    for block in range(word_size):
        blocks.append(bytes(CRYPT.sample(key_set, len(key_set))))
    return tuple(blocks)

# sudoko_key
#  - should be a proper "markov" key
def make_boot_strap(sudoku_key):
    block = sudoku_key[0]
    return bytes(CRYPT.choice(block) for byte in range(len(sudoku_key) - 1))

################################################################################

# This section contains functions needed to
# create the multidimensional encryption grid.

# sudoko_key
#  - should be a proper "markov" key
def make_grid(sudoku_key):
    grid = expand_array(sudoku_key[0], sudoku_key[1])
    for block in sudoku_key[2:]:
        grid = expand_array(grid, block)
    return grid

# grid
#  - should be an X dimensional grid from make_grid
# block_size
#  - comes from length of one block in a sudoku_key
def make_decode_grid(grid, block_size):
    cache = []
    for part in range(0, len(grid), block_size):
        old = grid[part:part+block_size]
        new = [None] * block_size
        key = sorted(old)
        for index, byte in enumerate(old):
            new[key.index(byte)] = key[index]
        cache.append(bytes(new))
    return b''.join(cache)

# grid
#  - should be an X dimensional grid from make_grid
# block
#  - should be a block from a sudoku_key
#  - should have same unique bytes as the expanding grid
def expand_array(grid, block):
    cache = []
    grid_size = len(grid)
    block_size = len(block)
    for byte in block:
        index = grid.index(bytes([byte]))
        for part in range(0, grid_size, block_size):
            cache.append(grid[part+index:part+block_size])
            cache.append(grid[part:part+index])
    return b''.join(cache)

################################################################################

# The first three functions can be used to check an encryption
# grid. The eval_index function is used to evaluate a grid cell.

# grid
#  - grid object to be checked
#  - grid should come from the make_grid function
#  - must have unique bytes along each axis
# block_size
#  - comes from length of one block in a sudoku_key
#  - this is the length of one edge along the grid
#  - each axis is this many unit long exactly
# word_size
#  - this is the number of blocks in a sudoku_key
#  - this is the number of dimensions in a grid
#  - this is the length needed to create a needed markon chain
def check_grid(grid, block_size, word_size):
    build_index(grid, block_size, word_size, [])

# create an index to access the grid with
def build_index(grid, block_size, word_size, index):
    for number in range(block_size):
        index.append(number)
        if len(index) == word_size:
            check_cell(grid, block_size, word_size, index)
        else:
            build_index(grid, block_size, word_size, index)
        index.pop()

# compares the contents of a cell along each grid axis
def check_cell(grid, block_size, word_size, index):
    master = eval_index(grid, block_size, index)
    for axis in range(word_size):
        for value in range(block_size):
            if index[axis] != value:
                copy = list(index)
                copy[axis] = value
                slave = eval_index(grid, block_size, copy)
                assert slave != master, 'Cell not unique along axis!'

# grid
#  - grid object to be accessed and evaluated
#  - grid should come from the make_grid function
#  - must have unique bytes along each axis
# block_size
#  - comes from length of one block in a sudoku_key
#  - this is the length of one edge along the grid
#  - each axis is this many unit long exactly
# index
#  - list of coordinates to access the grid
#  - should be of length word_size
#  - should be of length equal to number of dimensions in the grid
def eval_index(grid, block_size, index):
    offset = 0
    for power, value in enumerate(reversed(index)):
        offset += value * block_size ** power
    return grid[int(offset)]

################################################################################

# The following functions act as a suite that can ultimately
# encrpyt strings, though other functions can be built from them.

# bytes_obj
#  - the bytes to encode
# byte_map
#  - byte tranform map for inserting into the index
# grid
#  - X dimensional grid used to evaluate markov chains
# index
#  - list that starts the index for accessing grid (primer)
#  - it should be of length word_size - 1
# block_size
#  - length of each edge in a grid
def _encode(bytes_obj, byte_map, grid, index, block_size):
    cache = bytes()
    index = [0] + index
    for byte in bytes_obj:
        if byte in byte_map:
            index.append(byte_map[byte])
            index = index[1:]
            cache += bytes([eval_index(grid, block_size, index)])
        else:
            cache += bytes([byte])
    return cache, index[1:]

# bytes_obj
#  - the bytes to encode
# sudoko_key
#  - should be a proper "markov" key
#  - this key will be automatically checked for correctness
# boot_strap
#  - should be a proper "markov" bootstrap
def encrypt(bytes_obj, sudoku_key, boot_strap):
    _check_sudoku_key(sudoku_key)
    _check_boot_strap(boot_strap, sudoku_key)
    # make byte_map
    array = sorted(sudoku_key[0])
    byte_map = dict((byte, value) for value, byte in enumerate(array))
    # create two more arguments for encode
    grid = make_grid(sudoku_key)
    index = list(map(byte_map.__getitem__, boot_strap))
    # run the actual encoding algorithm and create reversed map
    code, index = _encode(bytes_obj, byte_map, grid, index, len(sudoku_key[0]))
    rev_map = dict(reversed(item) for item in byte_map.items())
    # fix the boot_strap and return the results
    boot_strap = bytes(rev_map[number] for number in index)
    return code, boot_strap

# string
#  - should be the string that you want encoded
# word_size
#  - length you want the markov chains to be of
# plain_chars
#  - characters that you do not want to encrypt
def encrypt_str(string, word_size, plain_chars=''):
    byte_obj = string.encode(CODEC)
    encode_on = set(byte_obj).difference(set(plain_chars.encode()))
    sudoku_key = make_sudoku_key(encode_on, word_size)
    boot_strap = make_boot_strap(sudoku_key)
    cyphertext = encrypt(byte_obj, sudoku_key, boot_strap)[0]
    # return encrypted string, key, and original bootstrap
    return cyphertext.decode(CODEC), sudoku_key, boot_strap

def grid_size(string, word_size, plain_chars):
    encode_on = set(string.encode()).difference(set(plain_chars.encode()))
    return len(encode_on) ** word_size

################################################################################

# The following functions act as a suite that can ultimately
# decrpyt strings, though other functions can be built from them.

# bytes_obj
#  - the bytes to encode
# byte_map
#  - byte tranform map for inserting into the index
# grid
#  - X dimensional grid used to evaluate markov chains
# index
#  - list that starts the index for accessing grid (primer)
#  - it should be of length word_size - 1
# block_size
#  - length of each edge in a grid
def _decode(bytes_obj, byte_map, grid, index, block_size):
    cache = bytes()
    index = [0] + index
    for byte in bytes_obj:
        if byte in byte_map:
            index.append(byte_map[byte])
            index = index[1:]
            decoded = eval_index(grid, block_size, index)
            index[-1] = byte_map[decoded]
            cache += bytes([decoded])
        else:
            cache += bytes([byte])
    return cache, index[1:]

# bytes_obj
#  - the bytes to decode
# sudoko_key
#  - should be a proper "markov" key
#  - this key will be automatically checked for correctness
# boot_strap
#  - should be a proper "markov" bootstrap
def decrypt(bytes_obj, sudoku_key, boot_strap):
    _check_sudoku_key(sudoku_key)
    _check_boot_strap(boot_strap, sudoku_key)
    # make byte_map
    array = sorted(sudoku_key[0])
    byte_map = dict((byte, value) for value, byte in enumerate(array))
    # create two more arguments for decode
    grid = make_grid(sudoku_key)
    grid = make_decode_grid(grid, len(sudoku_key[0]))
    index = list(map(byte_map.__getitem__, boot_strap))
    # run the actual decoding algorithm and create reversed map
    code, index = _decode(bytes_obj, byte_map, grid, index, len(sudoku_key[0]))
    rev_map = dict(reversed(item) for item in byte_map.items())
    # fix the boot_strap and return the results
    boot_strap = bytes(rev_map[number] for number in index)
    return code, boot_strap

# string
#  - should be the string that you want decoded
# word_size
#  - length you want the markov chains to be of
# plain_chars
#  - characters that you do not want to encrypt
def decrypt_str(string, sudoku_key, boot_strap):
    byte_obj = string.encode(CODEC)
    plaintext = decrypt(byte_obj, sudoku_key, boot_strap)[0]
    # return encrypted string, key, and original bootstrap
    return plaintext.decode(CODEC)

################################################################################

def convert(number):
    "Convert bytes into human-readable representation."
    assert 0 < number < 1 << 110, 'Number Out Of Range'
    ordered = reversed(tuple(format_bytes(partition_number(number, 1 << 10))))
    cleaned = ', '.join(item for item in ordered if item[0] != '0')
    return cleaned

################################################################################

def partition_number(number, base):
    "Continually divide number by base until zero."
    div, mod = divmod(number, base)
    yield mod
    while div:
        div, mod = divmod(div, base)
        yield mod

def format_bytes(parts):
    "Format partitioned bytes into human-readable strings."
    for power, number in enumerate(parts):
        yield '{} {}'.format(number, format_suffix(power, number))

def format_suffix(power, number):
    "Compute the suffix for a certain power of bytes."
    return (PREFIX[power] + 'byte').capitalize() + ('s' if number != 1 else '')

################################################################################

PREFIX = ' kilo mega giga tera peta exa zetta yotta bronto geop'.split(' ')

################################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Markov Demo')
    demo = MarkovDemo(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please post the actual problem, so we can fix that.

Comment: mister, you are truly a marvel at missing the point!

Comment: You say "The exception and program source are posted above".  In fact, only the exception is posted, so we can't help you figure out where you went wrong.  Probably you've inadvertently converted your bytestream to Unicode at some point, but we can't help you fix that without knowing what your code looks like!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python HOWTOs from the Python v3.1.1 documentation, there is a helpful section regarding Unicode HOWTO. The table of content contains an entry to [Python’s Unicode Support](http://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support) that explains string & byte.

---

### The String Type

```
>>> b'\x80abc'.decode("utf-8", "strict")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0:
                    unexpected code byte
>>> b'\x80abc'.decode("utf-8", "replace")
'\ufffdabc'
>>> b'\x80abc'.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
'abc'
```

---

### Converting to Bytes

```
>>> u = chr(40960) + 'abcd' + chr(1972)
>>> u.encode('utf-8')
b'\xea\x80\x80abcd\xde\xb4'
>>> u.encode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\ua000' in
                    position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> u.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
b'abcd'
>>> u.encode('ascii', 'replace')
b'?abcd?'
>>> u.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
b'&#40960;abcd&#1972;'
```

---

One possible solution to the problem listed above involves covert all occurrences of 
**.encode(CODEC)** with **.encode(CODEC, 'ignore')**. Likewise, all **.decode(CODEC)** become **.decode(CODEC, 'ignore')**.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are by definition a sequence of bytes that only have meaning when interpreted with the knowledge of the encoding.  That's one reason why the equivalent of Python 2's string type in Python 3 is the bytes type.  As long as you know the encoding of the strings you're working with, I'm not sure you specifically need to recode it just to compress/encrypt it.  Details of what you're actually doing might make a difference, though.

Answer (score 1):

Python's decode has error settings. The default is strict which throws an exception.

Wherever you are doing the decoding, you can specify 'ignore' or 'replace' as a setting, and this will take care of your problems.

Please see the [codecs](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html) documentation.